# I am not understand that code properly. Can some one help me to explain that code properly?

Tags: html, input, numbers

I write a code for make an input for number only. But there is something which I don't understand.
here is the code.

```
$("input[name='numonly']").on('input', function(e) {
    var fornum = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $(this).val(fornum);
});
```

In this code I am not understand how this .replace method is work and what is this "/[^0-9]/g".
And one more thing is .replace is method of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` is a string method. [This MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should help you. MDN is an incredible resource, and it's worth looking there first for answers before asking here.